# Passing a list of values between pages in react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React/React-native. I am trying to add a key-value pair in the JSON body which is the output of screen 1 having the following components:

1. A textbox which is to input a name
2. A textbox which is to input an email
3. A button, Types that navigates to Screen 2

The components on screen 2 are:

1. Two single-option dropdown lists with labels type 1 and type 2 that have three options each- "a", "b", "c".
2. A SAVE button to save the options chosen.

Initially, the JSON data produced from screen 1 **WITHOUT** the functionality of the Types button was:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
name: Name,
email: Email})
```

but now I want the output from screen 1 to be:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
name: Name,
email: Email,
types:[type1:"a", type2:"b"]
})
```

where type1 and type2 are the labels of the two dropdown lists and the options selected are "a" and "c" respectively after pressing a SAVE button on screen 2 and then navigating to screen 1. I have used the following useState methods for name and email for screen1:

```
const [Name, setName] = useState("")
const [Email, setEmail] = useState("")
```

and after making Types as a functional button on screen 1:

```
const [Name, setName] = useState("")
const [Email, setEmail] = useState("")
const [Types, setTypes] = useState([])
```

The below code is to update the name and the email with a Types button on screen 1:

```
<TextInput
label='Name'
value={Name}
onChangeText={text => setName(text)}
/>

<TextInput
label='Email'
value={Email}
onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
/>

<Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate("screen_2")>
Types
</Button>
```

What should be my onPress function in the button, Types(Screen 1) and button, Save(Screen 2) and how do I update the JSON body after saving my options on screen 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like React Router, you should check how to pass state with it. If not you might want to create a Redux store to save state relevant to the whole application

Comment: I am using react-navigation as of now. Can I still use that?

Comment: [Passing parameters to routes | React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/) look into this, I think you can